# Align items on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

Please, how can I align items on the left (reduce horizontal spacing) ?

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[\textbullet]  first
\item[\textbullet]  second
\item[\textbullet] third

\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 6):

Easy job with `enumitem` package, using `\setlist{labelsep=*}` will do it globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %% used for showing frames
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{labelsep=*} %% set here.
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet]  first
\item[\textbullet]  second
\item[\textbullet] third
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you want this locally for a single instance, you can use

```
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=*]
```

instead of `setlist`.

[image]

Also, instead of typing `\textbullet` every time, you can use

```
 \begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
```

(*bullet comes by default in first level itemize environments*, hence I used `$\circ$` for a change.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%\setlist{labelsep=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=*,label=$\circ$]
\item  first
\item  second
\item third
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to reduce the spacing between the bullets and the text, use `leftmargin option like

```
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=*,leftmargin=1pc]

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%\setlist{labelsep=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=*,leftmargin=1pc]
\item  first
\item  second
\item third
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** You can do it without any packages by adding

```
\setlength\leftmargini{1em}
```

to your preamble. Adjust the value `1em` appropriately for your need.

Comment: `\textbullet` is used by default in first level `itemize` environments, so in your example it's useless.

Comment: @egreg: True. I have written it inside parenthesis before the second code.

Comment: i add this \usepackage{enumitem}and \usepackage[showframe]{geometry} , the code is: \begin{itemize}[labelsep=*,leftmargin=1pc]
\item  first
\item  second
\item third
\end{itemize} but it did'nt work! i have this error Something's wrong--perhaps missing \item

Comment: Have you an idea please about the error ?

Comment: @researcher: Perhaps you don't have [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) installed? What distribution are you running? See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)

Comment: i have used this code \begin{list}{\labelitemi}{\leftmargin=1em}\item first \end{list}  and it works